# Saving Objects from Parse data using Swift instead of Objective-C

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller

I'm converting my `ViewController` from **Objective-C to Swift**.

I was wondering if **`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is the smartest thing to still be using** (or if that will load too slow), and if I should be using it the same way.

I'm using it to get my `Parse` data and save it to my `App Group` and/or `NSUserDefaults`.

```
    // Query Parse
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"data"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            NSMutableArray *localMatchup = [@[] mutableCopy];

            for (PFObject *object in objects) {


                // Add objects to local Arrays
                [localMatchup addObject:[object objectForKey:@"matchup"]];

                // App Group
                NSString *container = @"group.com.ramsden.playoffs";
                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];

                // Matchup
                [defaults setObject:localMatchup forKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                NSArray *savedMatchup = [defaults objectForKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                self.matchupArray = localMatchup;
```

Update:
I tried Lamar's answer below, but am getting an error on the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock line that says: `'([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void' is not compatible to 'PFArrayResultBlock?`

[image]
Here's a closer look at the specific line:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
func GetBackFromParse(localMatchUp:NSMutableArray){
var query = PFQuery(className: "data")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil
    {

        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]{

            for SingleObject in objects
            {

                var matchup = SingleObject["matchup"]
                localMatchUp.addObject(matchup!)

                 // do whatever you want to do
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @Lamar, thanks for the response!  I think what you're doing makes sense to me, the only thing so far is that I'm getting an error on the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` line that says: '([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void' is not compatible to 'PFArrayResultBlock?`.  Any idea?

Comment: replace with what i have on the code **query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in**

Comment: Yup, that works.  And for the part where you put `// do whatever you want to do`, is that corresponding to the parts of my code where I have `// App Group` and `Matchup`?

Comment: yeah where you had to create the instance of **NSUserDefaults**

Comment: Gotcha.  Seems like I'm close, but I'm getting a error on `localMatchUp.addObject(matchup!)` line "Use of unresolved identifier localMatchup".  I'm assuming because in my ObjC I specified that mutable array, but in the Swift I'm not seeing that its done that?  Am I on the right track there, or what do you think?

Comment: are you using my function?

Comment: Yeah I am using your function

Comment: Just added a snapshot (in my original question above) of what I have so far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88895/discussion-between-lamar-and-srmr).